# How to display sticky post always at the top (before regular post) in wordpress?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress code as shown below in which the **modified post displays at the top**.

```
   $temp_args = [
        'post_type' => array('current-channel', 'post', 'current-episodes'),
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby' => array(
            'feat_yes' => 'ASC',
            'post_type' => 'ASC',
            'modified' => 'DESC',
            'date' => 'DESC'),
        'posts_per_page' => $data->{"no_articles_" . ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE},
        'tax_query' => [
            [
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $cat_today,
            ],
        ],

    ];
    $q = new WP_Query($temp_args);
```

At this moment, order by is done in the following way with the modified post displays at the top.

```
'orderby' => array(
    'feat_yes' => 'ASC',
    'post_type' => 'ASC',
    'modified' => 'DESC',
    'date' => 'DESC'),
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the code above so that sticky posts are displayed at the top before the regular post.

The order should be in a way that **sticky post should always come at the top** and then **all the regular post**.

Comment: Can you read article for the sticky post ?

Comment: Sticky post is used only for  built-in post not for custom post type.

Comment: get post id and add that post before you call the posts loop. Ex: <sticky post></sticky post><posts loop></posts loop>

Comment: One more way add ACF(Advance Custom Field) from backend, So you can easily filter the sticky posts.

Comment: If you need help regarding ACF then i will explain the flow.